# html helper included in elements in cakephp not working with wamp

Tags: php, html, cakephp, xampp, wamp

I am working with cakephp.i have designed a homepage for a website.here i have inluded elements viz header.ctp, main.ctp and footer.ctp.And i call them in default.ctp using $this->element.
in each element i have used html helper 
likeHtml->image('Logo.png');?>
now when i deploy it on xxamp its working as expected
but when i migrated the same onto wamp its not giving the output
instead of showing image for

```
 <? echo $this->Html->image('Logo.png');?>
```

it is showing text

```
 Html->image('Logo.png');?>
```

i am using cakephp 2.4.2.
xamp 
php 5.3.5

wamp:
php 5.3.0

Comment: You are amazing.  Thanks for asking the question I couldn't figure out how to google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it working...
I just replaced

```
 <? ........   ?> with 
<?php ......  ?>
```

while declaring the php code.
 :)

Comment: Simply don't use short tags, never.